# Linear Predictive Coding example in MATLAB

Tags: discrete-signals, linear-systems, autoregressive-model, lpc, linear-prediction

I have some data that is highly correlated and I wanted to see if I could try and encode it using linear predictive coding (LPC). Here is how I've been understanding the process:

**Encoding**

1. Generate predictive filter coefficients
2. Filter signal with these coefficients to obtain and error signal $r[n]$.
3. Check if $r[n]$ is white.
4. If it is, store the variance of $r[n]$ along with the coefficients and you are done.
5. If not, increase order until (hopefully) $r[n]$ becomes white.

**Decoding**

1. With the encoding variance, produce a white signal.
2. Pass that white signal through the inverse filter.
3. You produce a signal $s[n]$ that has the same autocorrelation sequence and power spectrum as your original.

I've completed all the encoding steps - computed my coefficients, checked if my residual signal was white (autocorrelation is a delta function) and then stored its variance. However, the trouble comes during the decoding process. I took the variance I encoded, produced white noise, and filtered it with the inverse filter. Not only was my signal nowhere near a representation of my old signal, but the two signals had very different autocorrelation sequences as well. I've posted my code and my outputs below. I mainly just want to know if I'm misunderstanding something about LPC or if I'm implementing it wildly incorrectly.

```
load('amp.mat') %this gets loaded as the variable y with timestamp t

order = 15;
[a,variance] = aryule(y,order);
error = filter(a,1,y);

%Now check to see if error is white

[acs, lags] = xcorr(error,'coeff');
plot(lags,acs), grid;
```

[image]

```
noise = sqrt(variance)*randn(length(y),1);

%compare noise to error signal
plot(t,error,t,noise)
```

[image]

```
%synthesize signal
yrecon = filter(1,a,noise);
%actual signal, as produced by our residual
yact = filter(1,a,error);

plot(t,yrecon,t,yact);
title('Signal vs synthesized signal')
```

[image]

```
%check autocorrelation sequence of each and plot
[yacs, ylags] = xcorr(y,'coeff');
[yracs, yrlags] = xcorr(yrecon, 'coeff');
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(yrlags,yracs), grid
title('Autocorrelation sequence of reconstructed signal')
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(ylags, yacs), grid
title('Autocorrelation sequence of signal'}
```

[image]

Comment: wow it's exremely efficient to store only the variance of $r[n]$... ;-) consider a signal of length 1 G samples and you reduce it to a few prediction coefficients and a single variance ? something wrong ?

Comment: I agree that something seems wayyyy off haha. I mean I've tried increasing the number of prediction coefficients, but it neither makes the error 'more white' nor does it seem to make the auto correlation sequences more similar. I apologize, but I'm just really out of my depth here, I've looked all over for examples of implementing LPC for compression but I can't find any worked out examples so I've been trying to do it myself. I just figured that if I can get the residual to be white by removing all correlations in the signal, I've finished the encoding process. I'm guessing that's not true?

Comment: do you know what LPC is used for and how it does achieve its purpose ?

Comment: LPC is mianly used for speech because it's designed to fit the model of our vocal system. Our speech is modeled as a filter that is excited by either an impulse train or white noise. I do not know how it achieves its purpose. Although it's used mainly for speech, I don't see why it can't be used for any general signal that's correlated and can be reduced to some residual white noise. Maybe I'm misunderstanding everything, but I would really appreciate it if you could tell me how I could correct my already existing implementation and/or my understanding of LPC.

Comment: You are ok with the **predictive** part of the LPC. But it seems you have a problem with the **coding** part of it; that's where the **compression** actually takes place. You should consider the **quantization** stage carefully. I suggest you read *Introduction to Data Compression* by Khalid Sayood. For a full grasp of LPC and other data compression methods.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the suggestion! Am I wrong in assuming that all I need to store are my prediction coefficients along with my variance? And I'm not doing the quantization step yet since I want to see how accurate I can get with the actual prediction coefficients. Do you know of any example code for this sort of thing? I think it would be really illustrative to see a worked out example, but I'm struggling to find any code that even does it for speech. I do want to learn the theory and read the source you told me about, I'm just a little pressed for time.

Comment: Okay I'm quickly beginning to see the error in my ways. I can't just model the residual signal by white noise and call it a day. I have to do a better job of modeling the excitation signal, which is where the quantization comes in (if I want compression). Quantizing the excitation gives us the impulse train that we use to excite the filter and reconstruct our signal. Thus we can characterize our signal by the prediction coefficients and the amplitudes and intervals for the quantized excitation. Is this what you were getting at?

Comment: the **residual** is your signal to **encode**. So you will quantize and transmit the residual samples instead of the raw signal samples. Your **gain** is that, the residual signal has a lower variance than the original signal and hence needs less number of bits to encode (at the quantizer step) at a given distortion. You need to read about **quantizers** before seeing why this is so.